# Socket Connection Failed when Invoke it In Anther Function

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to do a program which simulates a fully connected networking.

I plan to create thread to present the nodes in the networking and each one will have to send and receive messages to and from each other.

I specify that there are totally 9 nodes.

For each node, I have a function run() which will specify the tasks for each node (thread).

---

```
def establish_c(input_id, maxS, local_conns, curr_port):
  incr = 0
  while (incr < id):
      tmpS = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      curr_port += 1
      tmpS.bind((ip, curr_port))
      tmpS.connect((ip, basePort + incr*100  + 1))
      local_conns.append(tmpS)
      incr += 1

   while (incr < maxS - 1):
      conn, addr = local_l.accept()
      local_conns.append(conn)
      incr += 1

   return

def run(*input):
   .... // Other code here, and also set up the input values for establish_c

   if True:
      establish_c(id, maxS, local_conns, curr_port)
```

---

The above code doesn't work and an error is displayed:

> error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

---

However, if the codes within establish_c() are appended onto the codes within run(), then every connection works fine.

---

```
def run(*input):
    incr = 0
    while (incr < id):
        tmpS = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        curr_port += 1
        tmpS.bind((ip, curr_port))
        tmpS.connect((ip, basePort + incr*100  + 1))
        local_conns.append(tmpS)
        incr += 1

    while (incr < maxS - 1):
        conn, addr = local_l.accept()
        local_conns.append(conn)
        incr += 1
```

I am confused why this happens?

Comment: What is the `id` in `while (incr < id):`? Shouldn't that be maybe `input_id` when used in the first example, since that's the name of the argument?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I made a very silly error here. Thanks a lot